# Chakra UI : Why tooltip is showing on the top left corner of the screen instead of showing on top of the element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chakra-ui

createdByModal is basically a chakra modal and I'm using tooltip in it.Whenever i hover on the icons the tooltip shows me on the top of the screen instead of on top of the icon.In the photo you can see the ignore element is showing on the top left corner

---

[image]

```
const CreatedByModal = () => {
  return (
    <Stack
      spacing={"4"}
      margin={"0px !important"}
      alignItems={"center"}
      px={{ base: "2", lg: "6" }}
      pt={"2"}
    >
      <HStack justifyContent={"space-between"}>
        <Tooltip
          bg={"white"}
          textAlign={"center"}
          color={"black"}
          placement="top"
          label="Tip"
          aria-label="A tooltip"
        >
          <AiFillWallet size={"1.2rem"} color={"#b1bad3"} />
        </Tooltip>
        <Tooltip
          bg={"white"}
          textAlign={"center"}
          color={"black"}
          placement="top"
          label="Ignore"
          aria-label="A tooltip"
        >
          <AiFillEyeInvisible size={"1.2rem"} color={"#b1bad3"} />
        </Tooltip>
      </HStack>
    </Stack>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you wrapped your components that want the tooltip with `forwardRef`?

https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/tooltip#usage

Or wrap your icon component in a span

https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/tooltip#with-an-icon

Comment: Actually, I'm not using custom card to show tooltip. Anways, I wrapped the icon with span and it works. Thanks!! . May i know what issue i was having ??

Comment: I would assume it just needed a parent element of the icon to attach a `position: relative` style to